# How to fix leaping of UIStackView when I change one of content's size using UIView.animate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get a few collapsable UIView in the `UIStackView`. But when the animation starts, all the objects leap, so the animation is not smooth. How can I fix it?

I tried to use `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` according to StackOverflow and other blog posts, but still no luck. I tried to call them directly on animated UIView and on the UIStackView. Also, I tried to change the height of the animated UIView using `UIView.frame` and height constraints. The first case even doesn't change the size, with the second one - this bug.
Also, I tried to use `UIView.AnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent`, no luck.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                           delay: 0.0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                           options: [UIView.AnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent], animations: {
                self.heightConstraint.constant = 60

                self.rowsParent.isHidden = true
                self.detailsParent.isHidden = true
                self.setNeedsLayout()
                self.layoutIfNeeded()

                DashboardVC.shared!.mealsParent.setNeedsLayout()
                DashboardVC.shared!.mealsParent.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
```

This code is expected to get smooth changing of the UIView size, so the height of UIStackView will be changing continuously too. 
But. The UIView height is changing continuously, but the height of the parent UIStackView changes immediately.

Gif:
https://gph.is/g/4V5PYPZ

Comment: _But. The UIView height is changing continuously, but the height of the parent UIStackView changes immediately_ I **think** that's expected. That is if you animated from 0 to 1000 in 1000 seconds you would immediately see the height set as 1000, even thought it won't happen until 1000 seconds later. But I'm not sure I have to test that myself too.

Comment: @Honey Yes, if the animation will take 1000 seconds, child `UIView` will be changing its size for 1000 seconds (1 point per second in your case), but the parent `UIStackView` will change its size to 1000 immediately. And this effect is undesirable. It needs to make parent `UIStackView` to change its size according to **current child sizes**. Not to the size which will be in 1000 seconds. Because in this case, we see animation bug like on the gif attached to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use animation option `.layoutSubviews` to make layout changes animatable.

See detailed in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions/1622543-layoutsubviews)